# AngularJS Directive: Attaching a function from the controller to ng-click

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've run into some trouble trying to write a directive to make a generic tool-tip which accepts as arguments a user id, and different actions associated with that id. Each action has it's own method in the controller and it's own icon.

This is the HTML

```
<tr ng-repeat="user in users"
    row-actions id="user.id" actions="[{'action': editUser ,'icon': 'edit'}, {'action': removeUser, 'icon': 'trash'}]">
    <td>{{user.name}}</td>
    <td>{{user.unit.name}}</td>
    <td>{{user.roleName}}</td>
    <td>{{user.active ? 'ACTIVE' : 'NON_ACTIVE' | translate}}</td>
</tr>
```

This is the directive

```
myApp.directive('rowActions',['$compile', function($compile){
      return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
          id: '=',
          actions: '='
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attr) {
          var div = angular.element('<div class="row-actions"></div>');
          for (var i=0; i < scope.actions.length; i++) {
            div.append('<span class="row-action icon icon-' + action.icon + ' icon-white" ng-click="' + action.action + '(' + scope.id + ')' + '"></span>');
          }

          element.append(div);

          $compile(element);
        }
      };
    }]);
```

Basically, the methods are editUser and removeUser, I'd like to be able to call them as editUser(user.id), etc, but I can't get it to compile.
I tried sending them as strings ('editUser'), and in the example they are sent as functions. Neither works.

Please take a look,
Thank you

Comment: receive actions as a string. change this `actions: '='`  to `actions: '@'`. if this doesnt work please setup a plunker

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, one immediate problem is that you never define `action`, so `action.icon` and `action.action` inside your `for` loop is going to give you an error.

However, even if you change this to `scope.actions[i].action`, this will still not work, because you have no `editUser` property on the current (isolate) scope.

Instead, I think you need something like this:

```
for (var i=0; i < scope.actions.length; i++) {
  div.append('<span class="row-action icon icon-' 
              + scope.actions[i].icon 
              + ' icon-white" 
              + ng-click="actions['+ i + '].action(' + scope.id + ')' 
              + '"></span>');
}
```

However, I think this whole thing would be much easier if you made use of a directive template:

**template.html**:

```
<div class="row actions">
  <span ng-repeat="action in actions" 
        ng-click="action(id)" 
        ng-class="action.icon"
        class="row-action icon icon-white"></span>
</div>
```

Which makes your directive much simpler

```
myApp.directive('rowActions',['$compile', function($compile){
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: {
      id: '=',
      actions: '='
    }
    templateUrl: 'path/to/template.html'
}]);
```

Comment: thank you very much for your answer. I will check the first method now but I find that using your second method I cannot append the template to an existing element, as I wanted (notice it's used through an attribute). My use case is to show on hover.